# Trouble setting up SFML in CodeBlocks

Tags: codeblocks, sfml

Tried to add the SFML library but I get an error:

`cannot find -lsfml-graphics-d / -window-d / system-d`

and I don't know what to do.

In the Debug Linker settings, I have this:

[image]

In the Release Linker Setting I have this:

[image]

And this is the error:

[image]

And I only changed this:

[image]

and this:

[image]

Nothing more.
I am new to libraries and things like that so please if you can explain the things I have to do to repair this. Thank you and have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Go to the sfml file and then double click on it. When you double click on it, you should see bin, doc, examples, include, lib, license.md, and readme.md. Double click on bin and copy all of the files to your project folder. This should help fix the errors.